# pandas data frame fail to resample

Tags: pandas, dataframe

When I convert my Stock data from daily to weekly using the following code

```
weekly =daily.resample("W").last()
```

when I take weekly it gives weekly closing prices but when I put the closing price of weekly in daily it gives NaN error

I try

```
daily["weekly_close"] = weekly["Close"]
```

please see the attached pic for error.[here's my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNURz.jpg)

Comment: Hello ! Please try to be more specific and read about how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can better help you. Also, never post code as images

Comment: I want to resample the daily data in to weekly and then want to put the weekly closing prices in daily dataframe. weekly and daily both data frame prices are correct when I see separately, but when i merge them in daily, weekly become NaN

Comment: `daily["weekly_close"] = daily.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W'))['Close'].transform('last')`

Comment: it gives the error "Length of values (564) does not match length of index (2645)"

Comment: I corrected it. daily.resample("w-fri").last()   the error was missing fri in resampling method.